# FIND distinct value from comma separated single string

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this and I want to select distinct value in single column:

```
  ID        Value

  1       13245|43558

  2       45961|5051

  3       43558| 5059
```

I need output Like this:

```
13245,43558,45961,5051,5059
```

Comment: This is why you should normalize your data. A trivial task is now very difficult.

Comment: Why should i normalize because I am getting piped value according to my condition for different ID

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that:

```
  select group_concat(distinct trim(substring_index(substring_index(value, '|', n.n), '|', -1)) separator ',' ) as `values`
  from table1 t 
  cross join (select 1 as n union all select 2 ) n
  order by `values`
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f33bb/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this query :**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(Value)) from table;
```